# How to implement InApp Purchase iOS for this Pay per view type of app?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am working on an app that serves new movies every week and users have to buy a movie to be able to watch it. Once an user purchases a movie they can watch it any number of times. We have our own user registration and login system. I want to know  do i have to create an In App Product on the iTunes Connect For every movie? We don't want to restore purchases to the different users using same apple id as well, will Apple allow that? I am really confused guys, I'd really appreciate some ideas.

Comment: if you want that user can see movie any number of time you have to create Non-Consumable (one time payment) IAP but to create IAP for every Movie might be not possible.You can make registered user on basis of membership if user join the membership then user able to see movie.

Comment: In-app for every movie is probably not OK with apple. Not sure may be OK for them but still doesn't sound good. The only way is to keep user's downloads on your server-side and ask the user to register to retrieve his downloaded list. And use a single in-app item to add item to the movie list and that in-app should be a consumable one.

Comment: @RJE there could be multiple movies releases each week. A single in app product won’t suffice in that case. How do i handle that scenario??

Comment: @Frankenxtein Which way did you choose to handle it? I am facing the same issue which you did and I am thinking about the good approach which will work for me and end-users.

Comment: @user2990759 i had to choose a renewable subscription module like Netflix, as the approach of in-app purchase for every single product was not feasible for us. However, if you must,  i suggest you to make the in-app purchases consumable instead of non-consumable,  like renting a movie on apple movies. You get the idea.

Comment: Yea, we are going to "consumable" direction